# How to get internet speed in brightscript

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

In one of my case, I want to send the current internet speed. So I am not able to find any solution.

I am not able to find how I can achieve it. Is there any way to get in Roku brightScript

Comment: your issue is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Your Current Internet Speed Is check for use speedtest.net.
Internet Speed Check-in ROKU its required simply two-step :

Step 1: Go->settings->Network->Check Cconnection-> OK 'Its message display is connection check was successful.

Step 2: Go->settings->Network->About->Internet download speed

Not required Any specific code and Logic apply For ROKU. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I want in my code not by following this. There are one event roSystemLogEvents from this we will get DownloadSpeed.But I am unable to get.

Comment: @bishalseth Thank you. In a roSystemLogEvents Check to Roku channel Working or not. I have two routers. one network works fine but another network is not working. I check the Log or status using roSysyemLogEvents.

Comment: Could you check are you getting DownloadSpeed or not from there.look at the link .https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifsystemlog.md